# Is this line creating globals?

Tags: javascript, global-variables, var

Is this line creating globals?

```
var first=second=third=fourth=fifth="Hello, ";
```

I am not entirely sure how to test it :)

Comment: You can test to see if something is global by looking in `window`.  `console.log(window.first)`.

Comment: @Rocket I will try, (btw, applejack>pinkie pie)

Comment: @Chuck, yours is just a direct link to jsfiddle.net.  Obviously the OP knows how to run javascript, so I hardly see how that's helpful.

Comment: @Yim: Those are really weird ways to spell "Rarity".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`first` will be declared as a local variable, but the others will be global.

To fix this, try the following:

```
var first, second, third, fourth, fifth;
first = second = third = fourth = fifth = "Hello, ";
```

Or all on one line:

```
var first, second, third, fourth, fifth = fourth = third = second = first = "Hello, ";
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes, all but `first` are global in this case. You can test in your browser's console by running

```
(function() { var x = y = 1; })();
console.log(y); // 1
```

Perhaps you want `var y, x = y = 1;`

Answer (score 2):

First will be local, the rest are global. See [this script from JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7DtHN/1/).

Answer (score 1):

Yes it is, declare your variables first:

```
var first,second,third,fourth,fifth;
first=second=third=fourth=fifth="Hello, ";
```

Will do the same thing except the variables will all be in the expected scope.

The way you have you are only declaring a variable called `first`, and are using the four other variables without declaring them, so they are globals.